# System that can access database offline using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently developing a system using PHP and MySQL, what is required of the system is that it should allow the user be able to access the database on a standard GUI online (web browser) and should also be able to access the database offline, now can anyone help me with a method of how to make this possible.

The idea i have right now (me thinking out of the box) is using local host database manager like xampp which will be offline and an online database manager were the system will be hosted but cant figure out how will both databases be synchronized so that they stay the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync online & offline databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200252/how-to-sync-online-offline-databases)

Comment: You can try to find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707859/mysql-database-sync-between-two-databases

Comment: Install XAMPP on every client? Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two databases maybe you will have to use a mirroring system. This one, wil help you to mantain the database syncronized with the database of the server with the local or not accessible database. You also can have a look at this link for more information [Right way to mirror a PHP/MySQL setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471273/right-way-to-mirror-a-php-mysql-setup)